# when i try to add value to variable Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I was trying to to add value from JSON using `alamofire`. Everything is working fine but when I try to add Value from JSON than got an error.

Here what I have done :

```
func getFeedVideo(){

    let API_KEY = "<key>"
    let UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID = "PLqQMDoH89jqEoHMTsxxyMz1Hym_pOViq6"
    let CHANNEL_ID = "UCcMUpFCaFhlyjZyy9d9LeRA"
    let parameters = ["part":"snippet","channelId":CHANNEL_ID,"playlistId":UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID,"key":API_KEY]

    Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems", parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

        if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: Any]{


                for video in JSON["items"] as! NSArray {

             // create video object of the JSON responds 

                    let videoObj = Video()
```

I was try Value this way

```
  videoObj.videoID = video.value(forkeypath:"")
```

But Xcode suggest me to add as anyObject

```
                     videoObj.videoID = (video as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "") as! String


                    print(video)

                }


        }
```

[Here is A screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BReIg.png)

I was searching for problem reason; I found something but I don't understand.

Here is this problem reason

1. While type-checking 'getFeedVideo' at /Users/faizulhasan/Desktop/StaticTableView/StaticTableView/VideoModel.swift:15:5
2. While type-checking expression at [/Users/faizulhasan/Desktop/StaticTableView/StaticTableView/VideoModel.swift:22:9 - line:45:8] RangeText="Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems", parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

   ```
       if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: Any]{


               for video in JSON["items"] as! NSArray {

                   // create video object of the Json responds 

                   let videoObj = Video()
                    videoObj.videoID = (video as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "")


                   print(video)

               }


       }
   ```

   }"

   3. While type-checking expression at

   [/Users/faizulhasan/Desktop/StaticTableView/StaticTableView/VideoModel.swi
   ft:32:26 - line:32:86] RangeText="videoObj.videoID = (video as 
   AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "")"

   4. While type-checking expression at

   [/Users/faizulhasan/Desktop/StaticTableView/StaticTableView/VideoModel.swi
   ft:32:45 - line:32:86] RangeText="(video as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: 
   "")"

Comment: Go reset that API key that you pasted into a public site, it's now in the revision history forever; be careful not to do that again (for your own sake :).

Comment: Thank's,  i forgot to delete it

Comment: What is the reason for using KVC method `valueForKeyPath` and what is the reason for bridge casting `as AnyObject`?

Comment: Xcode force me to add as Anyobject .. i was trying to add value from youtube using youtube api.

Comment: `value(forKeyPath: "")` is nonsense. Cast `JSON["items"]` to Swift Array `[[String:Any]]` and get the value representing the `videoID` for the proper key. If you confuse the compiler by using typeless objects like `NSArray` the compiler will confuse you.